# Spark: remove all duplicated lines

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset `ds` like this:

```
ds.show():

id1 | id2 | id3 | value  |
1   | 1   | 2   | tom    |
1   | 1   | 2   | tim    |
1   | 3   | 2   | tom    |
1   | 3   | 2   | tom    |
2   | 1   | 2   | mary   |
```

I want to remove all duplicate lines (note: not the same as distinct(), I do not want to still have a distinct line, but to remove both lines) per keys `(id1,id2,id3)`, the expected output is:

```
id1 | id2 | id3 | value  |
1   | 3   | 2   | tom    |
2   | 1   | 2   | mary   |
```

here I should remove line 1 and line 2 because we have 2 values for the key group.

I try to achieve this using:

```
ds.groupBy(id1,id2,id3).distinct()
```

But it's not working.

Comment: No surprise if you look up distinct in SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `window` function with `filter` on `count` as below

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, 1, 2, "tom"),
  (1, 1, 2, "tim"),
  (1, 3, 2, "tom"),
  (2, 1, 2, "mary")
).toDF("id1", "id2", "id3", "value")

val window = Window.partitionBy("id1", "id2", "id3")

df.withColumn("count", count("value").over(window))
  .filter($"count" < 2)
  .drop("count")
  .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---+---+---+-----+
|id1|id2|id3|value|
+---+---+---+-----+
|1  |3  |2  |tom  |
|2  |1  |2  |mary |
+---+---+---+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working fine like this, but is it possible to keep still the duplicated line if the value is the same ? I forgot to mention this (I modified the question)

Comment: for example the 3rd and 4th line with same value, and in output dataset I want to keep only one line (distinct)

Comment: How should your output look like ?

Comment: it should be the same, I only modified the input

Comment: I created a new topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68099936/spark-remove-duplicated-rows-with-different-values-but-keep-only-one-row-for-d if you can help me